# c# - Can I refactor functions that have similar inputs but call different services into one generic function?

Tags: c#, generics, design-patterns, asp.net-web-api2, refactoring

I am looking for a way to combine x amount of very similar CRUD functions into one without having to use x amount of if else statements to check the type of a generic.

I have Web API controllers that I want to make calls from like this:

```
Service.Get<FooModel>(number, type, part, version);
```

This is to prevent having to have an extremely similar function for 40+ API endpoints. The issue is when I receive this in my service, I have to check the type of the generic given and compare with those 40+ object types in the one function. All of the models currently inherit from a base inherited model.

#### Current generic function

(Create, Update, Delete functions are similar):

```
public T Get<T>(string documentNr, string type, string part, string version) where T : InheritedModel, new()
{
    try
    {
        T model = new T();

        if (typeof(T) == typeof(InheritedModel))
        {
           using (var repo = new InheritedModelConsumer(ref _helper))
           {
                model = (T)repo.Get(documentNr, type, part, version);
           }
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(FooModel))
        {
            using (var repo = new FooModelConsumer(ref _helper))
            {
                model = (T)(object)repo.Get(documentNr, type, part, version);
            }
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(ComponentModel))
        {
            using (var repo = new ComponentModelConsumer(ref _helper))
            {
                model = (T)(object)repo.Get(documentNr, type, part, version);
            }
        }
        else if (typeof(T) == typeof(BarModel))
        {
            using (var repo = new BarModelConsumer(ref _helper))
            {
               model = (T)(object)repo.Get(documentNr, type, part, version);
            }
        }
        ... and so on
        ... and so on
        ...
        else
            throw new Exception("Type T structure not defined");

        return model;
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

        throw;
    }
    finally
    {
        _helper.Dispose();
    }
}
```

This does work, but if it is possible I am looking for something where I can say at run time, "oh I have this object of Type T, and well since I know the functions all have the same inputs I'm going to instantiate this consumer of Type TConsumer, call consumer.Get(inputs), and then return an object of T to whatever API controller called me."

#### Edit

Example of a simple consumer class in use

```
    internal sealed class FooConsumer : RepositoryConsumer<Foo, FooRepository, FooFilter>
        {
            public FooConsumer(ref SqlHelper helper) : base(ref helper) { }

            public List<Foo> GetAll(string token)
            {
                return _repo.Get().Where(x => Extensions.StringContainsToken(x.AccountName, token)).ToList();
            }
        }
```

Repository Consumer that all consumers inherit from .
T is the model, K is the Repository (custom ORM class), and O is Filter for the WHERE clause the ORM executes.

```
     public abstract class RepositoryConsumer<T, K, O> : IDisposable, IRepositoryConsumer<T> where T : class, new() where K : Repository<T, O>, new() where O : QueryFilter, new()
        {
            /// <summary>
            /// Repository instance
            /// </summary>
            protected K _repo;

            /// <summary>
            /// Only constructor avaialble. MUst pass SqlHelper instance for transaction support
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="sql"></param>
            public RepositoryConsumer(ref SqlHelper sql)
            {
                _repo = Activator.CreateInstance(typeof(K), new object[] { sql }) as K;
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Allow consumer initializations in using statements
            /// </summary>
            public void Dispose()
            {

            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Create instance of T
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="data"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public virtual int Create(T data)
            {
                return _repo.Create(data);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Bulk create instances of T
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="contract"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public virtual int Create(BaseBulkable<T> contract)
            {
                return _repo.BulkCreate(contract);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Get an instance of T based on a single PK field id
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="id"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public virtual T Get(long id)
            {
                return _repo.Get(id);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Gets all instances of T
            /// </summary>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public virtual List<T> GetAll()
            {
                return _repo.Get();
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Updates an instance of T
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="data"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public virtual int Update(T data)
            {
                return _repo.Update(data);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Updates an instance of T based on a single PK field id
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="id"></param>
            /// <param name="data"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public virtual int Update(long id, T data)
            {
                return _repo.Update(id, data);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Deletes an instance of T
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="data"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public virtual int Delete(T data)
            {
                return _repo.Delete(data);
            }

            /// <summary>
            /// Deletes an instance of T based on a single PK field id
            /// </summary>
            /// <param name="id"></param>
            /// <returns></returns>
            public virtual int Delete(long id)
            {
                return _repo.Delete(id);
            }
        }
```

Comment: You could register your consumers in a dictionary by entity type. `var repo = dict[typeof(T)];`.

Comment: What's unique about each consumer that separates it from a `RepositoryConsumer<T>`? If you can use the generic type `T` in your call to your DB or API you could just inject a `RepositoryConsumer<T>` or `IRepositoryConsumer<T>` and drop the `if-else`

Comment: Your `RepositoryConsumer` code can't be your actual code it doesn't even compile, a virtual function needs a body?

Comment: @JSteward Updated the question with the RepositoryConsumer code. The RepositoryConsumer actually takes 3 generic arguments each having to do with T, which is where I think I run into most of my problems with trying to slim down the service call, sorry. The RepositoryBase is from an internal Nuget package, my bad. So they do have function bodies it's just in an assembly.

Comment: @JSteward Updated with the correct code for `RepositoryConsumer`